# Date changes after going through $filter()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, graph, highcharts, filter

I’m trying to create a chart with highcharts, but the data seems to be off my one date. I tried logging the original its output is what I want but when I log “date”, it’s always off by one date.

Ex: console.log data.createdAt   → Jun, 30 2016

console.log date → Jun, 29 2016

```
chartData = _.map response.data, (data) ->
   console.log data.createdAt
   date = $filter('date')(data.createdAt, 'mediumDate')
   console.log date
```

Comment: I'm not too familiar with highcharts. What is mediumDate for?

Comment: it prints out the date format in 'MMM d, y'

Comment: what the format and the value of data.createdAt ?

Comment: here is an example of the output : 
2016-06-30T00:00:00.000Z

Comment: define timezone by specifying the third parameter, e.g. (+0430 or +0530) for better controllable result. Refer https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

Comment: thank you Ajay! I added timezone '+0530' to date and it worked. Would you like to answer the question and get credit for your input?

Comment: Great find @Ajay, please make that an answer. I'd upvote it for awareness

Comment: @SterlingArcher Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define timezone by specifying the third parameter e.g. (+0430 or +0530) for better controllable result.

SampleCode

```
$filter('date')(data.createdAt, 'mediumDate', '+0530');
```

[Angular filter date timezone link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date)